# Duplicated output when scraping in r using loops

Tags: loops, web-scraping, rvest

I'm new in R, and I'm finding some trouble when scraping. From each page, i have 60 products, i'm trying to get the first 3 pages, so 180 rows. The problem is that i get the 180 rows, but basically i'm having the same info from the first page 3 times. I'm using rvest and dplyr.

My code here:

```
fragance_data = data.frame()

for (i in seq(from = 0, to = 3)) {
   fragance_url = paste0("https://www.cultbeauty.co.uk/fragrance.list?pageNumber=", i)
  
fragance_page = read_html(fragance_url) 
  
links = fragance_page %>% html_nodes("a.productBlock_link") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.cultbeauty.co.uk", ., sep="") %>% unique()

name <- html_nodes(fragance_page, ".productBlock_productName")
name<- html_text(name)
rating <- html_node(html_nodes(fragance_page, ".productBlock"), "span.productBlock_ratingValue") 
rating <- html_text(rating)
price <- html_node(html_nodes(fragance_page, ".productBlock"), ".productBlock_priceValue") 
price <- html_text(price)

  
get_review = function(links) {
    pages = read_html(links)
    review = html_node(html_nodes(pages,".athenaProductReviews_topReviewSingle"),
                       ".athenaProductReviews_topReviewsExcerpt") %>%
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
    return(review)
}
review = sapply(links, FUN = get_review, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

get_rating = function(links) {
    pages = read_html(links)
    rating_single = html_node(html_nodes(pages,".athenaProductReviews_topReviewSingle"),
                       ".athenaProductReviews_topReviewsRatingStarsContainer") %>%
    html_attr(., "title")  %>% paste(collapse = ",")
    return(rating_single)
}
rating_single = sapply(links, FUN = get_rating, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

get_title = function(links) {
    pages = read_html(links)
    title = html_node(html_nodes(pages,".athenaProductReviews_topReviewSingle"),
                       ".athenaProductReviews_topReviewTitle") %>%
    html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
    return(title)
}
title = sapply(links, FUN = get_title, USE.NAMES = FALSE)


print(i)

fragance_data  = rbind (fragance_data , data.frame(links, name,  rating, price, review, rating_single, title,  stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}
```

Could someone help me identify what I'm doing wrong and how can i get the total rows without duplicated values?

Answer (score 0):

Page 0 and Page 1 are same. Thus start from page 1.

Here are the links for first three pages.

```
library(rvest)
library(dpyr)

for (i in seq(from = 1, to = 3)) {
  
  fragance_url = paste0("https://www.cultbeauty.co.uk/fragrance.list?pageNumber=", i)
  
   url = fragance_url %>%  read_html()  %>% html_nodes("a.productBlock_link") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.cultbeauty.co.uk", ., sep="") %>% unique()

  fragance_data = c(fragance_data, url)
}
```